# Why is there reverse flow in Fluent?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, turbines, cfd

I am simulating a axial turbine and number of cell are about 3000000.

Under relaxation factors are as follows:

Pressure: 0.1

momentum:0.1

Turbulent kinetic energy: 0.5

Turbulent dissipation rate: 0.5

Velocity formulation is relative.

Turbulence model is K-E relizable. The convergence of solution is monitored by checking the residuals of the numerically solved governing equations. Moreover, in order to judge the convergence, the behaviour of other quantities, such as the total pressure at the inlet and outlet boundaries, and torque coefficient generated by the rotor, are also monitored. Here, the default convergence criterion of each residual is reduced in order to allow the monitored quantities to stagnate at consistent values. It seems that convergence is ok but there is reverse flow!! why?

residuals :

[image]

torque coefficient:

[image]

total pressure at the inlet and outlet boundaries:

[image]

Mass flow rate:

[image]

I continued this run and is as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Residuals are almost constant. What is the reason?

Is convergence OK?

I am grateful that guide me about this case.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse flow is usually not a big deal, there's even an option in the text user interface to suppress the warning.  If you're using higher order discretization in your solver, you may want to instead try a first order approach first.  Get that to converge, then run a few iterations with second order and see if you still get reversed flow.  The solution obtained from the first-order method will provide good initial conditions for the second-order method.

The y-axis on your mass flow rate is hard to see, but it looks like the convergence is hovering around zero.  All the values on the y-axis look to be zero, which means that graph is zoomed in quite far.  Based on your residuals plot, I think your solution is pretty well converged at this point.

Comment: Thank for your answer.
I will perform your statement.
i think that you are right.
According to your statement, Is there any problem in this solution? In other words, in some simulation, it can be exist reverse flow and solution converges. Am i right?  I thought that a converged solution have not any revers flow. but according your statement, it can be exist reverse flow and solution converges.
Carlton, I didn't understood the following sentences, can you explain more?
"there's even an option in the text user interface to suppress the warning."

Comment: Other thing is that torque and inlet and outlet pressure are not stagnated.

Comment: I cannot cite any professional sources that say how much reverse flow is acceptable, however I can say from personal experience that many of my Fluent simulations, both steady and transient, contain warnings about reverse flow yet still produce correct results.  I would not worry about reverse flow too much; the residuals of mass/momentum/energy/etc. are much more important for gauging solution convergence.  To suppress reverse flow warnnigs, type into the text user interface (TUI):  `solve set flow-warnings? no`

Comment: Other thing is that torque and inlet and outlet pressure are not stagnated.

http://www.upsara.com/images/mgxf_66666.jpg

http://upsara.com/images/i4pm_555.jpg

Comment: Thanks, 
According " solve set flow-warnings? no", there is not any warnings about reverse flow. But Do you sure that this work affect on final solution?

http://upsara.com/images/yi33_delet_revers_flow.jpg

Comment: Your plots of torque and inlet/outlet pressure are curious though.  Can you try to run the simulation longer and see if they flatten out?  Also, are you certain that this is a steady-state problem, and that there's nothing in there that might cause it to be transient?

Comment: I think that the solution is not converged because torque and inlet/outlet pressure are not stagnated. Yes, I am continuing this run but they are not stagnated in iteration of 5640. it seems that they are reaching to stagnation. 
Yes, I am certain that this is a steady-state problem. but it is not too exact after massive separation(stall). I studied many papers about this case. Also, this run is near stall(massive separation).

Comment: Carlton, I continued this run, please see again topic.